# Autofill in Excel VBA returns error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a raw Excel file into a customized format. I added a picture below, so its easier to explain. I will address the requirements as steps too.

1) I need to get rid off all columns which include "Importo" or "Prezzo"
2) I need to extract the date from the remaining columns (Quantitá). First, I insert an empty row on top and then i apply right(cell,7).

So far, so good.
Then I want to autofill the remaining columns, but i get a 1004 error. In the example code I tried from J:O, but really id need it from J to the last column. I post the code (which works until the last row).

I was actually wondering if Autofilling is best practise here, maybe indexing though would be better?

```
Sub delete_col()
 Dim A As Range

    Do
        Set A = Rows(1).Find(What:="Importo", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If A Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        A.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop

    Do
        Set A = Rows(1).Find(What:="Prezzo", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If A Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        A.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop

Rows("1:1").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

ActiveCell.Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(R\[1\]C,7)"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("J1:O1"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that in the line `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(R\[1\]C,7)"`, the `\` is a kind of typo, which should be deleted.

Concerning the 1004 error, the easiest way to go around it, while doing AutoFill, is something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Range("A1:O1") = Range("J1")
End Sub
```

Thus, every value in `Range("A1:O1")` will be set with the value from `Range("J1")`.

---

However, your code uses a lot of `Select`, `Activate` and `ActiveCell`. Try to avoid these, because they are not considered good practices in VBA and may lead to different errors. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)